# Texturing. How to fix texture stretching?

Tags: texturing

I try to add bricks texture and looks so over stretched. I even tried with Brick texture node & had the same problem so I used image texture. How can i adjust this? Here is the screen shot
[image]

Adding mapping ..Still the same :(
[image]

Comment: Could you provide more details about how you are using this texture and how you are applying it? Please edit your question and provide some screenshots of you object, texture, material settings, node setup, and texture coordinates.

Comment: i just edited and added screenshot.sorry for confusion

Comment: You don't seem to provide provide any texture coordinates to your image. Either unwrap your object or use one of the builtin automatic ones

Comment: I added the mapping and still the same problem.i added the screen shot